# Pandas partially removes contents of cells in random order

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1')

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='processing')
```

This code reads one sheet of an excel file and copies all the data to an adjacent sheet, but when searching for sheets, it turns out that some of the information is lost both in the original sheet and in the new sheet. Each time the code is executed, a different amount of information is overwritten.

But how is this possible? If there is a clear command in the code to read the first sheet - what makes it change? The same questions apply to writing a new sheet.

The screenshot below shows three different categories with symptoms:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSdKR.jpg)

I use versions: Pandas - 1.4.4, Openpyxl - 3.0.10

For example: it works well in pycharm, but it doesn't work in Jupyter notebook.

My suspicion is that the code somehow reacts incorrectly to the characters that are in the text (emoji) and this text with tags. In the initial version, there were many columns, but only one is problematic - which is in the example. But I am an amateur, and I only express my assumptions. I've run out of solutions.

[Original file](https://dropmefiles.com/AXUvx)

Help me please. Best Regards.

My friend suggested this code, but it doesn't work either.

```
from html import unescape
from unicodedata import normalize
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'file.xlsx',
    engine='openpyxl',
    converters={
        'Описание - Description': lambda x: normalize('NFKC', unescape(x))
    }
)

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='processing')
```

Comment: On my laptop, nothing is lost.

Comment: For example: it works well in pycharm, but it doesn't work in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I tried it only in Jupyter Notebook on MacBook, and it worked well. Not the new code, but just reading as rewriting as suggested in the beginning.

Comment: But for what reason does it not work for me on several computers? any ideas?